# Get the Android camera Aperture and Exposure Time

Tags: android, camera

Is there any API instruction or calculation to obtain the android camera Aperture F value, and the Exposure Time?

The Camera API exposes methods to get the White Balance, the Focal Length, etc, but I couldn't find anything related to the Aperture and the Exposure Time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android Developer's Guide for [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), which is a class in the `android.media` API (not, the now deprecated `Camera` API), there is information for [Aperture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_APERTURE) and [Exposure Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME)

Sample code showing how it could be used is available at [ExifHelper](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-android/trunk/framework/src/com/phonegap/ExifHelper.java)

Comment: Useful answer, but please note: This answer contains mainly links, which is not recommended by Stackoverflow, because links can change. *(No vote)*

Comment: Actually, @SQLPolice it precisely answers the OP's question - not only providing the requested links to information, but also showing where to find the information should the links go down (i.e. the information required is in the `android.media` API not the deprecated `camera` API.

Comment: This answer is actually not relevant to camera exposure and aperture. The Media API is for already recorded media. The old Camera API has been deprecated and replaced by a new Camera API, not by the `android.media` API.